# Enumerate using numbers and letters, starting at E1.1

Tags: enumerate, theorems

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{task}{}[section]
\renewcommand*{\thetask}{E\thesubsection}
```

I defined a new theorem style but want it to enumerate like E1.1, E1.2, E1.3, etc. But my attempt produces only E1.0 enumerations. Why?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Without a working example it's hard to give a good answer, but try `E\thesection.\arabic{task}`.

Comment: You're my saviour. Thank you! That works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(All statements in this answer assume “usual circumstances”, whatever that means.)

`\thesubsection` is defined as `\thesection.\arabic{subsection}`, so it will *always* print the current `\thesection` (which in your case seems to be `\arabic{section}`), a `.`, and the number of the `subsection` counter in arabic algarisms. But the `subsection` counter only steps when you use a `\subsection`. Until then that counter won't change and the expansion of `E\thesubsection` will always be the same.

From your examples it seems you want to have `\thetask` print `<thesection>.<value of task counter>`. In this case, define it as such:

```
\renewcommand*{\thetask}{E\thesection.\arabic{task}}
```